# Run 32bit applications on Windows 10 64 Bit

Tags: 64-bit, windows-10, 32-bit

I've got a Windows 10 Computer (home edition), which has 4GB of Ram and an i5 processor. I need to run an old 32 bit accounting programme. The vendor said it won't release a 64 bit version (although a 64bit version exists, it's missing key features from the older version).

The programme installs fine, but when I click on the programme icon, it says the programme won't work on a 64 bit system.

What options do I have?

---

I've done a fair bit of research, but it seems to run up dead ends.

**1) WoW64**

[Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)

Apparently, this is supposed to let you run 32 bits on 64 bit Windows. However, I am not sure how to install it. I think it's for web servers only. However, [this Stack Overflow thread](https://superuser.com/questions/330029/wow-windows-on-windows-running-32-bit-apps-on-windows-7) says it can work on Windows 7, but doesn't explain how to set it up (or if it will work on Windows 10).

**2) XP mode**

[Link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7)

A 32bit Windows XP emulator. However, it seems to be for Windows 7 only. Also according to this [Stack Overflow thread](https://superuser.com/questions/245840/run-an-application-only-compatible-with-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine), you need Windows Professional.

**3) Virtual Box Machine**

[Link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Let's you emulate Windows. Seems overkill for my purposes. Plus I would need to buy a 32 bit Windows license. I think it would run slowly with 4GB of Ram.

**4) Partition drive into 32bit and 64 bit versions**
Apparently, you can use the free tool [EaseUS](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/windows-7-partition-manager/partition-windows-7-32-bit-for-free.htm) to split the drive into two and then install separate 32bit and 64 bit versions.

Again, seems overkill and it looks like I would need buy a 32 bit Windows 10 license.

Are these my only options?

---

Images

Installation

[image: Installation]

First run (From the error message I guess it's a 16-bit program)
[image: First run]

Clicking on programme
[image: When clicking on Programme]

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit will run 32 bit programs. Just install it.

Comment: The only problem you might have is really old programs can use 16bit installers which won't run on 64bit.

Comment: @DavidPostill I installed it, but when I click on the icon, it says it won't work on a 64 bit system, and I need to contact the vendor.

Comment: Then it may be a 32-bit program with a 16-bit installer as @DavidMarshall mentioned.

Comment: @big_smile What is the **exact error message**? Upload a screenshot to http://imgur.com/ and post the link.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106825/how-to-execute-16-bit-installer-on-64-bit-win7 Try the second answer with 24 votes.

Comment: Have you tried "compatibility options by right-clicking an application’s .exe file or shortcut, selecting Properties, clicking the Compatibility tab, and selecting a version of Windows the program worked properly on. If you’re not sure what the problem is, the “compatibility troubleshooter” can walk you through choosing optimal settings." - [Is Windows 10 Backwards Compatible With Your Existing Software?](http://www.howtogeek.com/219782/is-windows-10-backwards-compatible-with-your-existing-software/)

Comment: @DavidPostill I've uploaded the images. When I contacted the vendor, they told me it was 32 bit. But after looking carefully at the error message, I can see it is actually 16 bit. Whoops! I will research into running 16 bit apps on 64 bit Windows. (I'm not sure if it is possible).

Comment: "The vendor said it won't release a 64 bit version" - ask the vendor if they have a 32 bit version (with a 32 bit installer).

Comment: @DavidPostill. I will ask them, but when I email them previously, they said it is a 32 bit application (which is where the mix up came). It's only a small company, so I don't think they will make a 32 bit version (They have a 64bit version, but it's missing most of they key features).

Comment: It isn't possible to run a 16-bit application on 64-bit operating system.  Use a virtual machine with a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: @Ramhond Thanks, any recommendations. Apparently virtualbox doesn't run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, if you want to operate an older, 16-bit program, you have to be running a 32-bit version of Windows. [64-bit versions of the operating system simply do not support it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896458), as they lack the compatibility layer (they are compatible with the more widely used 32-bit software, however). There are some [other limitations of 64-bit Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/282423), but the key point here is that 16-bit programs won't execute.

**Edit:** After revisiting this question some time later, I'd like to address your findings in the OP.

1. **WoW64** lets you run 32-bit programs in a 64-bit Windows environment. It is built into the Windows operating system and does not require additional installation. Similarly, 32-bit installations of Windows can run 16-bit programs.
2. **XP Mode** was a feature of Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate, that allowed you to run the more popular at the time Windows XP in a virtual machine.
3. **Virtual Box**, or any virtual machine software (VMWare is another example) allows you to install an operating system inside and run it inside of your primary machine. This would be arguable the easiest way to achieve your goal as you could simply install the software onto a 32-bit virtual OS. If you gave the VM 2GB of memory access, on a 32-bit install, it would run okay. Sluggish, but okay.
4. **Partitioning your drive** would allow you to dual boot twin installations of Windows. This is a more permanent solution, and shouldn't be done IMO unless you can't run the VM.

Answer (score 3):

**This isn't 32-bit, it's 16-bit**

This would require you to be able run a 16-bit WoW memory space.

WoW16 stands for Windows on Windows.

The WoW started in windows 3.0, often called Windows for Workgroups.

Since this 16bit memory space is no longer available [you could install DOSBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/) to the system, install Windows 3.1 to DOSBox and run the application from there.

Your other option is to install a 32bit version of Windows 10 as a virtual machine and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box with Linux and [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)#Backward_compatibility) might do it.

Alternatively here is a tutorial [using DosBox](http://www.freezenet.ca/guides/compatibility-and-emulation/how-to-play-16-bit-windows-gamesapplications-on-a-64-bit-computer/).

Comment: You could always just install the old version of Windows in Virtualbox that it was compatible with

Answer (score 0):

To run 16-bit applications you can install [Winevdm](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm) which is Windows port of [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: That software is unnecessary for 32-bit windows applications on 64-bit versions of Windows.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need all of these above "solutions" ...

Just right-click on the icon of your 32bit program
In the properties windows
select "Compatibility"

Then Run the compatibility troubleshooter to test in which mode
your program run best

In my case selecting the mark by "Compatibility Mode" Windows XP SP2
was all what was needed to run the program perfectly!